# Angularjs - listening for list events

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've "borrowed" this directive code for my sortable list but I'm not sure how I can listen out for when a list item has been dragged into new position.

```
app
.directive('sortable', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            ngChange: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var toUpdate;
            var startIndex = -1;
            element.sortable({
                axis: "y",
                revert: true,
                start: function (event, ui) {
                    // on start we define where the item is dragged from
                    startIndex = $(ui.item).index();
                },
                stop: function (event, ui) {
                    // on stop we determine the new index of the
                    // item and store it there
                    var newIndex = $(ui.item).index();
                    var toMove = toUpdate[startIndex];
                    toUpdate.splice(startIndex, 1);
                    toUpdate.splice(newIndex, 0, toMove);

                    $timeout(function() {
                            scope.ngChange();
                    });
                }
            });

            scope.$watch('ngModel', function() {
                    $timeout(function() {
                            toUpdate = scope.ngModel;
                    });
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

How can I call a function in my Controller? Would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directive accepts ngChange, so to get notification you would use:

```
<sortable ng-change="onItemDragged()"></sortable>
```

On your controller you will have a function called onItemDragged:

```
$scope.onItemDragged = function() {
    // do something
}
```

See here for more info about ng-change directive:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange